# Can a POST request accept two callbacks and can the first pass data to the second?

Tags: javascript, express, post

I have the following `.post()` request:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const search_controller = require('../controllers/searchController');
const result_controller = require('../controllers/resultController');

//Search Routes

router.post('/', search_controller.search_create_post);

module.exports = router;
```

Could I add a second callback to it so that the first callback is run, then the second callback as such:

```
router.post('/', search_controller.search_create_post, result_controller.result_create_post)
```

Would I need a `next()` somewhere in those create functions? And could I also pass data from the `search_create_post` callback to the `result_create_post` callback? I would want to pass in the newly created Search object's id.

My current `search_controller.search_create_post` function is a such:

```
exports.search_create_post = (req, res, next) => {
    let newSearch = new Search({ search_text: req.body.search_text });

    newSearch.save((err, savedSearch) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send(savedSearch);
        }
    })
};
```

Comment: You could pass one callback that contains a function that calls the other two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use like this (based on how your functions are written):

```
// option A
router.post('/', search_controller.search_create_post, result_controller.result_create_post)

// options B
router.post('/', search_controller.search_create_post)
router.post('/', result_controller.result_create_post)
```

If search needs to pass data to result, you could set `req.search_data` in `search_create_post` and then get the value in `result_create_post`.

Take a look at https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html. There are a few good examples on this page.

```
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('ID:', req.params.id)
  next()
}, function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('User Info')
})

// handler for the /user/:id path, which prints the user ID
app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.end(req.params.id)
})
```

**based on your comment below:**

You might be able to do this...

```
exports.search_create_post = (req, res, next) => {
  let newSearch = new Search({ search_text: req.body.search_text });
  newSearch.save((err, savedSearch) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      req.searchData = savedSearch;
    }
    next();
  })
};
```

Comment: Where would I add the `search_data` to the `req` in `search_create_post`? I edited my main question to include my `search_create_post` function. Do I also need to add a `next` somewhere (as well as an `end`)?

Comment: Option A worked when I passed `next` and called it just as you said in my `search_create_post`, along with passing in the needed data through the `req`. This has taken my longer than I care to admit and it's finally worked. Thank you SO MUCH!